# How do I install packages from test.pypi.org using poetry?

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, python-poetry

I want to use a pre-release version of a package (https://test.pypi.org/project/delta-spark/2.1.0rc1/) in my project.

I'm using `poetry` to manage my `pyproject.toml`. How do I do this?

In other words what is the `poetry` equivalent of:

`pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ delta-spark==2.1.0rc1`

I tried:

- `poetry add delta-spark==2.1.0rc1`
- `poetry add --allow-prereleases delta-spark==2.1.0rc1`

Both give: `Could not find a matching version of package delta-spark`

---

```bash
$ poetry config --local repositories.test-pypi https://test.pypi.org/
$ poetry config --list | fgrep repositories
repositories.test.url = "https://test.pypi.org/"
repositories.test-pypi.url = "https://test.pypi.org/"
$ fgrep -A 3 tool.poetry.source pyproject.toml 
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "test-pypi"
url = "https://test.pypi.org/"
secondary = true
$ poetry add --group dev delta-spark==2.1.0rc1

Could not find a matching version of package delta-spark
$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is described [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/). Basically, you can add the repository via:

```
poetry config repositories.test https://test.pypi.org/simple/
```

and then make it available in `pyproject.toml` via:

```ini
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "test"
url = "https://test.pypi.org/simple/"
secondary = true
```

Then adding the dependency should work.

Comment: Skimming through the docs I thought this was only for publishing. Thank you!

Comment: So I tried it, but it doesn't work. Updated OP with info. I tried to name the repo `test` as well, same results.

Comment: @Kashyap The URL was incomplete, I updated my answer. Please check if it works now.

Comment: I had already tried that (`/simple`) too. As well as `/legacy`. Both give same error. Running with `-v -v -v` doesn't really help. I'll update teh OP. Does the solution you posted work for you?

Comment: nvm, I had missed updating `pyproject.toml`. Doesn't make sense to me that you have to specify the URL in two places. But anyway.. works now. TY.

Answer (score 1):

In poetry 1.5.0, `secondary = true` has been deprecated.

Here's a safer solution, to make sure that *only the package you want*
is downloaded from TestPypi:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "test-pypi"
url = "https://test.pypi.org/simple/"
priority = "explicit"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
my-package = {version = "0.1.1", source = "test-pypi"}
```

### Why is it safer ?

According to [poetry's documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#secondary-package-sources-deprecated),
secondary sources have been deprecated.

Using TestPyPi as a secondary source is problematic for two reasons:

1. It is applied to all your project dependencies, not just the ones for which you want to use the version from TestPyPi.
2. TestPyPi is always called for each dependency, even when a compatible version was found in the primary source.

This makes you vulnerable to [dependency confusion attacks](https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610):

Imagine you use some famous package `famous-package = "^1.2.0"` in your dependencies, and that this package does not exist on TestPyPi (because the developper never pushed it there).
Then *anyone* can push an infected version `1.99.99` of `famous-package` to TestPyPi, and your project will download it. It can then run arbitrary code on your computer.

To avoid this, poetry recommends replacing `priority = "secondary"` with `priority = "supplemental"`, which means the source will only be called if the primary source does not find any compatible package distribution.

But it's even safer to use `priority = "explicit"` and then explicitely chose which packages should be downloaded from TestPyPi.